# LinkedIn - Есть плюс в том чтобы соглашаться на приглашение на добавление от незнакомых рекрутеров?

Tags: linkedin

LinkedIn - Есть плюс в том чтобы соглашаться на приглашение на добавление от незнакомых рекрутеров?

Comment: Оффтопик, это не относится к программированию. Это о построении карьеры.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, плюсов в этом нет.

1. Ключевая рекомендация сайта - [не добавлять тех, с кем вы не работали](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20141003141124-10647407-linkedin-connections-should-you-connect-with-people-you-don-t-know) (более внятной ссылки не нашел под рукой). Хотя бы потому, что ваша сеть засоряется мусорными связями.
2. Напрашивается в друзья особая категория рекрутеров - так называемые ресерчеры, задача которых составить пул соискателей (см. [статью Алёны Владимирской](http://alenavl.livejournal.com/259064.html)). Они берут числом и вероятность нормального диалога сводится к нулю (большие паузы между фразами, потеря нити, отсутствие обратной связи....).